# Trying to adapt mergevec to work with the new OpenCV (2.4.5)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, windows-7, computer-vision

So like the title says I've been following [this](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html#Tutorial) tutorial which seems to be the go to tutorial for how to handle haar feature training using the OpenCV.

**Mergevec** is a utility that merged together vec files so that you could generate a large number of samples from relatively few images. Anyway, he has an exe but it appears to be for 32-bit OpenCV 2.4.3 while I have 64-bit version 2.4.5. Any help would be appreciated!

My version is built using cmake and Visual Studio 10 as the compiler

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! Hopefully others can make use of this too!

Basically you want to:

First add **mergevec.cpp** to the folder *\opencv\apps\haartraining* then add the following to *CMakeLists.txt*

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------
#  mergevec
# -----------------------------------------------------------
add_executable(opencv_mergevec mergevec.cpp)
set_target_properties(opencv_performance PROPERTIES
                  DEBUG_POSTFIX "${OPENCV_DEBUG_POSTFIX}"
                  OUTPUT_NAME "opencv_mergevec")
```

Comment: we have to add this to which _CMakeLists.txt_ ? To the on present in **opencv/apps/haartraining/** or to the one in our project folder? And if to the former, then do we have to compile opencv again?